# How to check if text stored in file contains new line character(Enter) using java?

Tags: java, newline

I'm trying to read data stored in text file and check if file's data contains new line character or not.
For example: if file contains data:

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
```

Then my program should say that first line contains new line character.

I tried using

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "test.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{                       
    char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
    for(char test: arr)
        if(String.valueOf(test) == System.getProperty("line.separator"))
            System.out.println("Contains new line");
}
```

and I also tried this code

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.contains(System.getProperty("line.separator")))
        System.out.println("Contains new line");
}
```

but to no avail.

My file does contains new line character. In notepad++ if I search for \n or \r\n then it does shows new line character in file. But some how my code is not recognizing it.

Comment: How does this relates to `selenium` tag?

Comment: I'm doing automation testing using selenium so I added. My bad, it should not be there. Thanks for update. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 5):

As you can read from the `BufferedReader#readLine` JavaDoc

> #### public String readLine()throws IOException
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

That is why your line has no line endings.

Comment: Is there a way around so that I can achieve this ?

Comment: You could use the read method and check each char or use use the readLine and assume that if the method returns a String that this string had a end line. But why you need this? Is this really necessary?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using selenium automation testing for one scenarios where I need to check that file should not contain any empty line or new line character. For empty line I have done it but for new line I'm still struggling.